# How to get specific field only in case if graphql require it?

Tags: graphql, nestjs, typegraphql

I've started to learn NestJs and GraphQL and created a simple backend:

I have posts:

```
import { Field, Int, ObjectType } from 'type-graphql';

@ObjectType()
export class Post {

    constructor ({ id, title }) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
    }

    @Field(type => Int, { nullable: true })
    id: number;

    @Field(type => String)
    title: string;

}
```

And I have Users

```
import { Field, Int, ObjectType } from 'type-graphql';
import { Post } from './post';

@ObjectType()
export class User {

    constructor({ id, name, postIds }) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.postIds = postIds;
    }

    @Field(type => Int)
    id: number;

    @Field(type => String)
    name: string;

    @Field(type => [Int])
    postIds: number[];

    // in case 'postIds' populating
    @Field(type => [Post])
    posts: Post[];
}
```

And NestJS (I think `type-graphql` library did it) generate schema.gql file for me:

```
# -----------------------------------------------
# !!! THIS FILE WAS GENERATED BY TYPE-GRAPHQL !!!
# !!!   DO NOT MODIFY THIS FILE BY YOURSELF   !!!
# -----------------------------------------------

type Post {
  id: Int
  title: String!
}

type Query {
  user(id: Int!): User!
}

type User {
  id: Int!
  name: String!
  postIds: [Int!]!
  posts: [Post!]!
}
```

And the last file with UserResolver:

```
import { Int, Resolver } from 'type-graphql';
import { Args, Query } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { User } from './models/user';
import { Post } from './models/post';

const post1 = new Post({ id: 1, title: 'title_1' });
const post2 = new Post({ id: 2, title: 'title_2' });
const post3 = new Post({ id: 3, title: 'title_3' });
const user1 = new User({ id: 1, name: 'Alex', postIds: [post1.id, post2.id] });
const user2 = new User({ id: 2, name: 'Kate', postIds: [post3.id] });
const allUsers = [user1, user2];
const allPosts = [post1, post2, post3];

@Resolver()
export class UserResolver {

    @Query(returns => User)
    user(@Args({ name: 'id', type: () => Int }) id) {
        const currentUser = allUsers.find(u => u.id === id);

        // please, remember next part of code
        currentUser.posts = [];
        currentUser.postIds.forEach(postId => {
            const currentPost = allPosts.find(p => p.id === postId);
            currentUser.posts.push(currentPost);
        });
        return currentUser;
    }

}
```

It's all. It is very simple. Now, I can request the next:

```
{        
    user(id:1) {
        name
        posts {
            title
        }
    }
}
```

And it works. But there is some problem. If the request would be next...

```
{
    user(id:1) {
        name
        postIds
        #posts aren't required anymore
    }
}
```

...the next code executes anyway

```
        currentUser.posts = [];
        currentUser.postIds.forEach(postId => {
            const currentPost = allPosts.find(p => p.id === postId);
            currentUser.posts.push(currentPost);
        });
```

I think it is not right. The idea of graphql is to take only the necessary data described in the query. And in my case, we get the `posts` and then cut them off. If in the future there will be a large nesting of `User.Post.IntroImage.Comment.User` then this will be ineffective.

Please tell me how to do it right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer :)

```js
    import { Args, Parent, Query, ResolveProperty, Resolver } from '@nestjs/graphql';
    import { User } from './models/user';
    import { Post } from './models/post';
    
    const post1 = new Post({ id: 1, title: 'title_1' });
    const post2 = new Post({ id: 2, title: 'title_2' });
    const post3 = new Post({ id: 3, title: 'title_3' });
    const user1 = new User({ id: 1, name: 'Alex', postIds: [post1.id, post2.id] });
    const user2 = new User({ id: 2, name: 'Kate', postIds: [post3.id] });
    const allUsers = [user1, user2];
    const allPosts = [post1, post2, post3];
    
    @Resolver(of => User)
    export class UserResolver {
        @Query(returns => User)
        user(@Args('id') id: number) {
            return allUsers.find(u => u.id === id);
        }
    
        @ResolveProperty()
        async posts(@Parent() user) {
            return user.postIds.map(postId => {
                return allPosts.find(p => p.id === postId);
            });
        }
    }
```

I just need add `@ResolveProperty` and graphql library exec it if in need.